# How can I draw this spiral (with vertical sides) in tikz?

Tags: tikz-pgf, draw, technical-drawing

How can I draw this spiral (with vertical sides) in tikz?

The only way I would know how, would be to copy and paste code to draw semicircles of different radius, followed by connecting the semicircles one at a time, which would take a very long time.

[image: spiral thing]

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX](//tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436). Questions about how to draw specific graphics that just post an image of the desired result are really not reasonable questions to ask on the site. Please post a minimal compilable document showing that you've tried to produce the image and then people will be happy to help you with any specific problems you may have.  See [minimal working example (MWE)](//tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) for what needs to go into such a document.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I hope nobody gets mad at me for reopening the question but I feel that for the first question one may make exceptions. Instead of copying you could use `foreach`.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
 \def\vlength{3}
 \def\hstep{0.6}
 \def\Xmax{9}
 \fill[gray!40] ({-(\Xmax+3)*\hstep},-\vlength)
 rectangle (\hstep/2,\vlength);
 \draw[thick,dashed] (-1*\hstep,\vlength)
 -- (-1*\hstep,-\vlength)
 arc[start angle=180,end angle=360,x radius={1.5*\hstep},
  y radius=0.75*\hstep]
  foreach \X in {1,...,\Xmax}
  {\ifodd\X
   --  ({\hstep*(\X+1)},\vlength) 
    arc[start angle=0,end angle=180,x radius={(\X+1.5)*\hstep},
   y radius={0.5*(\X+1.5)*\hstep}]
  \else
  --  ({-\hstep*(\X+1)},-\vlength)
   arc[start angle=180,end angle=360,x radius={(\X+1.5)*\hstep},
  y radius={0.5*(\X+1.5)*\hstep}]
  \fi}
  --  ({-\hstep*(\Xmax+2)},-1*\vlength);
 \draw[thick] (-1*\hstep,\vlength) 
 arc[start angle=180,end angle=0,x radius={0.5*\hstep},
  y radius=0.25*\hstep]
  -- (0,-\vlength)
  arc[start angle=180,end angle=360,x radius={0.5*\hstep},
  y radius=0.25*\hstep]
 (\hstep,-1*\vlength) 
 foreach \X in {1,...,\Xmax}
 {\ifodd\X
   -- (\hstep*\X,\vlength) 
   arc[start angle=0,end angle=180,x radius={(\X+0.5)*\hstep},
   y radius={0.5*(\X+0.5)*\hstep}]
 \else
  -- ({-\hstep*\X},-1*\vlength) 
  arc[start angle=180,end angle=360,x radius={(\X+0.5)*\hstep},
  y radius={0.5*(\X+0.5)*\hstep}]
 \fi} -- ({-\hstep*(\Xmax+1)},-1*\vlength) 
 arc[start angle=0,end angle=-180,x radius={0.5*\hstep},
  y radius=0.25*\hstep];
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Or with pgf keys.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[hstep/.initial=0.6,vlength/.initial=3,
Xmax/.store in=\Xmax,Xmax=9]
 \fill[gray!40] ({-(\Xmax+3)*\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/hstep}},-\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/vlength})
 rectangle (\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/hstep}/2,\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/vlength});
 \draw[thick,dashed] (-1*\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/hstep},\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/vlength})
 -- (-1*\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/hstep},-\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/vlength})
 arc[start angle=180,end angle=360,x radius={1.5*\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/hstep}},
  y radius=0.75*\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/hstep}]
  foreach \X in {1,...,\Xmax}
  {\ifodd\X
   --  ({\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/hstep}*(\X+1)},\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/vlength}) 
    arc[start angle=0,end angle=180,x radius={(\X+1.5)*\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/hstep}},
   y radius={0.5*(\X+1.5)*\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/hstep}}]
  \else
  --  ({-\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/hstep}*(\X+1)},-\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/vlength})
   arc[start angle=180,end angle=360,x radius={(\X+1.5)*\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/hstep}},
  y radius={0.5*(\X+1.5)*\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/hstep}}]
  \fi}
  --  ({-\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/hstep}*(\Xmax+2)},-1*\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/vlength});
 \draw[thick] (-1*\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/hstep},\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/vlength}) 
 arc[start angle=180,end angle=0,x radius={0.5*\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/hstep}},
  y radius=0.25*\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/hstep}]
  -- (0,-\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/vlength})
  arc[start angle=180,end angle=360,x radius={0.5*\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/hstep}},
  y radius=0.25*\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/hstep}]
 (\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/hstep},-1*\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/vlength}) 
 foreach \X in {1,...,\Xmax}
 {\ifodd\X
   -- (\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/hstep}*\X,\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/vlength}) 
   arc[start angle=0,end angle=180,x radius={(\X+0.5)*\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/hstep}},
   y radius={0.5*(\X+0.5)*\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/hstep}}]
 \else
  -- ({-\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/hstep}*\X},-1*\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/vlength}) 
  arc[start angle=180,end angle=360,x radius={(\X+0.5)*\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/hstep}},
  y radius={0.5*(\X+0.5)*\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/hstep}}]
 \fi} -- ({-\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/hstep}*(\Xmax+1)},-1*\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/vlength}) 
 arc[start angle=0,end angle=-180,x radius={0.5*\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/hstep}},
  y radius=0.25*\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/hstep}];
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Despite not being the OP, thanks for your unconditional continuous help.